# I want to add additional property to json string without transform the String to any object format

Tags: java, json

I want to add additional property to json string without transform the String to any object format (I am doing the transformation right now which taking 30 ms time, i want to avoid the transformation time), so is there any way to add property to the json string without transform the payload to any object format?

Ex:

```
{
  "type": "some type",
  "data": [{
    "email": "email id",
    "content": {
      "some filed": "filed value"
    }
  }]
}
```

i need my payload after the new field added like.,

```
{
  "type": "some type",
  "data": [{
    "email": "email id",
    "content": {
      "some filed": "filed value",
      "new field": "New value"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Try the `json-simple` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to slip in your new field at the end of `content`:

```
String json = "{ \"type\": \"some type\", \"data\": [{ \"email\": \"email id\", \"content\": { \"some filed\": \"filed value\" } }] }";
String newField = "\"new field\": \"New value\"";
json = json.replaceAll("(\"content\".*?)\\}", "$1" + Matcher.quoteReplacement("," + newField + "}") + "");
```